# "LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble" for a directive not used except in the preamble

Tags: pandoc, preamble

For a `markdown` doc that has the following preamble:

```
---
title: Cloud Capstone Task1
subtitle: Airline Dataset Queries 
documentclass: scrartcl
author: Stephen Boesch
geometry: "fontsize=9pt left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
fontsize: 9pt
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: yes        
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[C]{Airlines DataSet Queries}
- \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
---
```

And for which there are *zero* additional *tex* (or *pandoc*) directives in the corpus- the following error is stubbornly not going away:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.275 \usepackage
```

Why is it pointing to a line 275 .. there is no such `\usepackage` there..

Here is the `pandoc` command:

```
pandoc --toc -css pandoc.css -V fontsize=9pt --pdf-engine xelatex -V geometry:"left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm" -o Task1.pdf Task1.md
```

So what is happening here?

Comment: line 275 can refer to the line in some file input by your document (including some of the packages).

Comment: Your example works without any problems for me. Try checking that you're not using a custom template, and that you're using the most recent versions of Pandoc and TeX Live.

Comment: May depends on css source and some recent pandoc changes may now need -c xxx.css [and optional -s or -standalone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the *pandoc.css* were the issue. I had pulled it from a reputable source so had not considered that as a possible cause.

Later I will update on what precisely in the file has caused the mismatch.

Comment: If that's really the case, it would be a bug, as CSS is only used for HTML and EPUB (PDF is affected only if using an HTML-to-PDF engine).